# How to open an specific section of a chm file in Python?

Tags: python, chm

How can I open a .chm help file in a particular section using Python? Actually I am opening the file with the following function:

```
def help(self):
  # Open the help file
  os.startfile( os.getcwd()+"/config/help.chm")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to do it, but is more related to the hh program in Windows:

My help file was generated using the program chmprocessor which generate the chm file and I generate a hhk file (containing the references). Using this file I used the following code

```
def help(self)

  os.system("hh.exe d:/help.chm::/4_Userguide.htm#_Toc270510")
```

I think this is the way, If there are another easy way. please let me know.

Regards

german

Answer (score 3):

Other sugestion :

```
subprocess.Popen("hh.exe d:/help.chm::/4_Userguide.htm#_Toc270510")
```